# My UIView anchors in my custom cell keep changing when I scroll in my collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell, nslayoutconstraint

I have a messaging app and the messages displayed are in a collection view, i have a custom cell in which i have a text view that displays the message and then I put the textview inside of a UIView so I can give the message a background colour depending on the user that sent the message

My function in my custom cell sets the background view to the right or the left depending if the
message is from the current user or not

I do this by uploading in my message model the information if the message is from the current user or a different user by the UID as I'm using Firestore

What happens is the moment I have enough messages where I can scroll the collection view the constraints randomly start changing and some of the cells background view expand the entire width of the collection

I've tried putting my function in dispatchQueue and still get the same problems

any ideas ??

```
class MessageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var bubbleLeftAnchor : NSLayoutConstraint!
    var bubbleRightAnchor: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    var messagess : Message? {
        didSet {
                configure()
        }
    }
    

    let label : UITextView = {
        let lbl = UITextView()
        lbl.backgroundColor = .clear
        lbl.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        lbl.textColor = .black
        lbl.isEditable = false
        lbl.isScrollEnabled = false
        return lbl
    }()
    
    var bubble : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        return view
    }()
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        
        
        addSubview(bubble)
        bubble.addSubview(label)
        
        bubble.anchor(top: topAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, paddingTop: 10 , paddingLeft: 50, paddingBottom: 20)
        bubble.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 250).isActive = true
        
        
        label.anchor(top: bubble.topAnchor, left: bubble.leftAnchor, bottom: bubble.bottomAnchor, right: bubble.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 4)
        
        
        
    }
    
        
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    func configure() {
        
        label.text  =  messagess?.message
        bubble.backgroundColor =   messagess?.isFromCurrentUser == true  ? .green : .purple
        
        guard let messagess = messagess else {return}
         
        bubbleLeftAnchor =   bubble.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 12)
        bubbleRightAnchor =  bubble.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -12)
      
        if  messagess.fromId == Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid  {
        
            bubbleLeftAnchor.isActive = false
            bubbleRightAnchor.isActive = true
                
            } else {
                
                bubbleRightAnchor.isActive = false
                bubbleLeftAnchor.isActive = true
                
            }
            
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating ***NEW*** constraints every time you call `configure()`.

You need to move these two lines:

```
    bubbleLeftAnchor =   bubble.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 12)
    bubbleRightAnchor =  bubble.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -12)
```

from `configure()` to your `init()` function:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    
    addSubview(bubble)
    bubble.addSubview(label)
    
    bubble.anchor(top: topAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, paddingTop: 10 , paddingLeft: 50, paddingBottom: 20)
    bubble.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 250).isActive = true
    
    label.anchor(top: bubble.topAnchor, left: bubble.leftAnchor, bottom: bubble.bottomAnchor, right: bubble.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 4, paddingLeft: 4, paddingBottom: 4, paddingRight: 4)

    // create these constraints in init
    bubbleLeftAnchor =   bubble.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 12)
    bubbleRightAnchor =  bubble.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -12)
    
}
```

Comment: @farooq - if this answer solved your issue, be sure to mark it "Accepted" for the benefit of other users who may come across your question.

Comment: yes I did mark it but as I am new my reputation is still under 15 so not showing up but still gets registered

Comment: Whoops - I should have noticed that.